The difference in the meaning of "in" between "in the days after ~" and "in days after ~"
The following sentences are from news articles.

Some counties have scheduled public hearings on the challenges in
the days after Election Day.
In days after January 6, McCarthy said Trump admitted bearing some responsibility for Capitol attack.

I looked it up in the OALD and thought about it, and it seems that in the first sentence, "in" means "5. during a period of time," while in the second sentence, "in" means "6. after a particular length of time." Am I correct in my understanding?

Did you actually read the first sentence of the article itself, in your second example? Which effectively repeats the headline, but rephrases to ...in the days following... Why would you suppose the title and the first sentence might have different meanings?

@FumbleFingers I edited the original post, taking into account the part you pointed out.

@qna, Please don't edit your post after people have answered it, as subsequent readers will not be able to relate the answer to your edited post. Please reverse it. You can raise a new post.

@SeowjoohengSingapore Sorry

The second example is a headline.
The body text has the article:

... said publicly and privately in the days following the deadly riots at the US Capitol ...

Headlines frequently omit small words like articles.
The Ngrams show that the version with the article is far more common.  Although in days after appears to have some hits, a lot of them are false positives.
in days after

Thank you very much.

I edited the original post, taking into account the part you pointed out.

Please don't edit your post after people have answered it, as subsequent readers will not be able to relate the answer to your edited post.  Please reverse it.  You can raise a new post.
